# How can I group inputs with the same name created using useFieldArray() from react hook form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I have an array of translations as seen below:

```js
const translations = [
  {
    name: 'John',
    description: 'Some description',
    language: 'en',
    slug: 'some slug'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    description: 'Some description',
    language: 'fr',
    slug: 'some slug'
  },
  {
    name: 'John',
    description: 'Some description',
    language: 'de',
    slug: 'some slug'
  },
]
```

I could add or remove more translations. But, the way I need to render the form is different. It should look like this:

```
Name:
 1. English name input
 2. French Name input
 3. German Name input

Description:
 1. English description textarea
 2. French description textarea
 3. German description textarea
```

...and so on.

At present, I am looping through the fields array multiple times to group and render the inputs. For example:

```
const { register, control } = useForm<{ translations: Translation[] }>({
  defaultValues: {
    translations: myTranslations
  }
})
const {fields} = useFieldArrays({
  control,
  translations
})

return (
  <div>
  {
    // Render name
    fields.map((field, index) => (
      <input {...register(`translations.${index}.name`)} />
    ))
  }
  {
    // Render description
    fields.map((field, index) => (
      <input {...register(`translations.${index}.description`)} />
    ))
  }
  </div>
)
```

Is there an optimized approach where I can render the fields in just one loop rather than looping through fields multiple times and still have all the same fields organised under respective field names?

Comment: where is index coming from

Comment: why not return all the inputs in a single map

Comment: @cmgchess Updated the code to show from where the index is coming. I want to group fields by array properties. So, if the array of objects consists of the `name` property, then I need to render the inputs prefilling it with the name for each index sequentially. If I do it in a single map, it will not be rendered sequentially one after the other.